# Global Connection from SQL Server Database to VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, class, global

I want to create a global connection class from Sql server database to vb.net to make it easy in later editing the connection. Could anyone guide me the way to code both creating and calling to individual form?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your connection string in your web.config file. (this gives you a single point where you can change the connection string *without* needing to recompile your application, it also allows you to encrypt it in the future to protect your DB server).

I'd advise against using a single "connection" object for reuse.  Open and close a connection for each query or transaction.

Check out the Repository pattern instead.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Comment: and how could I call it from web.config file to use in my forms?

Comment: @tep -- this should help:  http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/08/26/Using-connection-strings-from-web.config-in-ASP.NET-v2.0.aspx